# Spreadsheet parse error

Tags: google-sheets

Is anyone able to advise what's wrong with this formula:

```
=IF(B3<TIMEVALUE("08:00 AM"),TIMEVALUE("08:00 AM"),B3)
```

I already tried to replace the `,` with `;`, but still the same parse error.
The formula does work in MS Excel, but not in Google spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you copied and pasted the formula from a web page into Google Sheets? Have you reviewed the spreadsheet regional settings? Are you sure that the quotation marks are straight quotes (`"`) instead of curly quotes (`“`, `”`)?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the formula so either:

- for the sheet's locale either the language or choice of delimiter is unsuitable (or both are).
- the formula in the sheet incorporates characters that are not displayed (and have not been copied into the OP above).

The latter tends to happen when formulae are copied out of Comments on SE (when invisible line breaks may be copied across). They *can* be seen if formulae are copied into Word or other suitable software.